# Quartz.Net method DateBuilder.TodayAt() on the StartAt() JobScheduler

Tags: c#, quartz.net

What would happen if I used the DateBuilder.TodayAt to create a date to start my job, but that time had already passed, would the job start?

Example:

Let's say I have a job that I want Quartz to run it everyday at 5 am.
But I'm setting this at 9 am today, would this code work?

```
.StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(5, 0, 0))
.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
.WithIntervalInHours(24)
.RepeatForever())
```

So, since the datebuilder created a datetime for today at 5 am, this job would never start, right? So it can never repeat forever.
Or would Quartz.net understand that and fire it anyway tomorrow at 5 am and so on?

Would there be a better way to do this? Creating a job that runs everyday at 5 am?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look into cron schedules (http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html). If your scheduler thread isn't running from 4am til 10am then your simple one will likely run at 10am and then every 24 hours from then I believe. The cron one will try to run at 5am every day no matter when the last one ran.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to create this job by setting the time for the next day, so is certain that the specific time has not yet passed.

Like this:

```
.StartAt(DateBuilder.TomorrowAt(5, 0, 0))
```